# How to pass and collect info what was pressed in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I need more help with my first Table View app.
I have .plist with continents, countries and other info:
[image: World.plist]

I work with a StoryBoard and I have 3 View Controllers (MasterVC - for continents, MiddleVC - for countries, DetailVC - for detailed info). I have already continents displayed in UITableView on my MysterVC. Now I want to pass information about what was pushed to the MiddleVC, for example that Europe was pushed and the to display European countries in a table view on my MiddleVC.

I guess that I should do it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//is it correct way to catch the info about which continent was pressed?
NSString *ContinentName = [[world allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//I don't know how to pass the info forward

}
```

Or maybe I should use segue for passing data?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showMiddle"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];

//??is everything what needed here??

[[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
}
}
```

And I am not sure how to deal with the passed info from MasterVC, here in MiddleVC. Although I prepared some initial coding:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//I think countries arrays will be needed here
NSArray *namesOfAfricanCountries = [africa allKeys];
NSString *AfricanCountryName = [namesOfAfricanCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray *namesOfEuropeanCountries = [europe allKeys];
NSString *EuropeanCountryName = [namesOfEuropeanCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//how to feel cells only with the proper continent's countries?
cell.textLabel.text = ???;

return cell;
}
```

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: This is a good tutorial. Maybe you could glance at [link](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UINavigationController? If so:

1. Setup a 'push' segue from your Master VC to your Detail VC and have a property in your details VC to hold the 'continent' dictionary.
2. implement 'prepareForSegue', here you can use the indexPathForCell: on the sender argument to find out which cell was tapped.
3. Use the row in the index path to locate the country in your dictionary
4. In your prepare for segue, use segue.destinationViewController to get a handle on your detail VC and set it's continent property to the country dictionary from your data source. (you only want to pass forward the continent dictionary containing the countries in that continent, not your whole data source).

Then in the detail VC' cellForRowAtIndexPath:

1. then if you only want to display the country name in the cell assuming the names are keys...

NSString *key = [self.continentDict allKeys][indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text  = key;

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Now I have a strange problem with segue method. I named my segues with new identifiers and changed it also in segue method and the app is crushing all the time.